# Explode a string

Tags: php

I have a string as follows :

```
      $str = "am_customers.customer_key,am_customers.add_dt,CONCAT(am_customers.first_name,'',am_customers.last_name) as 
             name,am_customers.cell_phone,am_customers.crm_phase_key,  am_customers.source,am_customers.location_key,am_customers.hub_key,
             am_customers.crm_priority,am_customers.update_dt";
```

I want to explod a string by comma. But the problem is with open and close brackets , When I try to expload a string by comma, I will get the result like as follows

```
          Array
         (
           [0] => am_customers.customer_key
           [1] => am_customers.add_dt
           [2] => CONCAT(am_customers.first_name
           [3] => ''
           [4] => am_customers.last_name) as name
           [5] => am_customers.cell_phone
           [6] => am_customers.crm_phase_key
           [7] => am_customers.source
           [8] => am_customers.location_key
           [9] => am_customers.hub_key
           [10] => am_customers.crm_priority
           [11] => am_customers.update_dt
         )
```

But I want the result like as follows :

```
       Array
     (
       [0] => am_customers.customer_key
       [1] => am_customers.add_dt
       [2] => CONCAT(am_customers.first_name,'',am_customers.last_name) as name
       [3] => am_customers.last_name) as name
       [4] => am_customers.cell_phone
       [5] => am_customers.crm_phase_key
       [6] => am_customers.source
       [7] => am_customers.location_key
       [8] => am_customers.hub_key
       [9] => am_customers.crm_priority
       [10] => am_customers.update_dt
     )
```

Is there any way to do this like i want above ?

Thank You.

Comment: preg_split using a regular expression that only includes commas outside of parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the comment by @Devon you can achieve this with `preg_match_all`:

`preg_match_all( '/[^C\(,]*(?:(?:Cf\.|C(?!f)|\([^)]*\))[^C\(,]*)*/', $str, $matches );`

Regex Source: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=907316

I just tested this code and it seems to do what you are asking for:

```
$str = "am_customers.customer_key,am_customers.add_dt,CONCAT(am_customers.first_name,'',am_customers.last_name) as 
             name,am_customers.cell_phone,am_customers.crm_phase_key,  am_customers.source,am_customers.location_key,am_customers.hub_key,
             am_customers.crm_priority,am_customers.update_dt";

$matches = [];
preg_match_all( '/[^C\(,]*(?:(?:Cf\.|C(?!f)|\([^)]*\))[^C\(,]*)*/', $str, $matches );

/*
* Trims each match, removes empty string matches, and resets array keys.
*
* Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#111091
*/
$clean = array_map( 'trim', $matches[0] );
$clean = array_filter( $clean, 'strlen' );
$clean = array_values( $clean );

var_dump( $clean );
```

**Documentation**

`array_filter`: http://php.net/array_filter

`array_map`: http://php.net/array_map

`array_values`: http://php.net/array_values

`preg_match_all`: http://php.net/preg_match_all

Comment: Hi @rideron89,
preg_match_all( '/[^C\(,]*(?:(?:Cf\.|C(?!f)|\([^)]*\))[^C\(,]*)*/', $str, $matches ); 
Above line is giving me an error. something is wrong in that i think.